# Adicionar libraria para Android do Github

Tags: android, library

Como posso adicionar um projeto do Github como uma libraria no Android Studio?

Queria implementar [esta](https://github.com/Scalified/fab), mas não faço ideia como o fazer. Tenho os requisitos todos.

Comment: Está lá descrito como. É só adicionar `compile 'com.scalified:fab:1.1.3'` no bloco *dependencies* do seu build.gradle

Comment: mas eu não preciso de fazer download do repositório?

Comment: Não precisa @ihavenokia, o Gradle já faz a gerência dessa dependência para você.

Comment: Ok, realmente já consegui coloca-lo! Conhece algum artigo bom que explica como isso funciona? Obrigado

Comment: Libraria é uma espécie de junção de Library + Livraria ?